# Unable to click on temporary pop up appears for 2.5 Seconds while scripting for Selenium

Tags: c#, jquery, selenium, webdriver

[image: screen shot]Upon clicking on page, an application pop up (not a window) appears for 2.5 seconds. and when ever I am clicking on that pop up link (given on that appeared pop up) generate an error "Object Reference not set to an instance" and it stops. for the same time (2.5 seconds) a snippet of HTML code (above in screen shot) generates for the same pop up on view source and disappears. I tried switchedto().Alert, switchedto.Window(name) and Switchedto.Frame, Window handles but non of them are working. My expectation are more with JSscript executor I used below

```
string jQuerySelector = ".quick-add" + "li:has(a:contains('Appointment'))";
string findAppointment = "return $(\"" + jQuerySelector + "\").get(0);";
WebElement ChooseAppointment = (WebElement)js.executeScript(findAppointment);
ChooseAppointment.Click();
```

Comment: Is there any way to get access to the website you are testing?

Comment: Hi Curtis, I have prepared a document for you including url, username and password. but here I can not share that. please provide me your email address so that i can send you that

Comment: This is horrific. Why can't you use native Selenium selectors here?

Comment: Hi user, my email is curtis.miller@ableengineering.com

Answer (score 0):

Seems it can't find an element with defined jQuerySelector .quick-addli:has(a:contains('Appointment')):

```
string jQuerySelector = ".quick-add" + "li:has(a:contains('Appointment'))";
```

or

```
string jQuerySelector = ".quick-addli:has(a:contains('Appointment'))";
```

**EDIT**: Try this instead:

```
WebElement ChooseAppointment = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector('a:contains("Appoinment")'));
ChooseAppointment.Click();
```

Comment: @user1692178, use either ".quick-add" (to get the <a> element) or "li:has(a:contains('Appointment'))" (to get the <li>), but not both at the same time.